# Reading Xml and Update

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

I trying to read a xml file from resource and update it,save as new xml file.I got an error as **Specified method is not supported** while i am saving my changes.

```
   var s =  Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Customer.xml", UriKind.Relative));

            SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            dialog.DefaultExt = "*.xml";
            dialog.Filter = "Excel Xml (*.xml)|*.xml|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == false)
                return;

            XDocument data = XDocument.Load(s.Stream);

            XElement customerElement = data.Descendants("Customer").Where(c => c.Attribute("ID").Value.Equals("1")).FirstOrDefault();
            if (customerElement != null)
            {
                customerElement.SetElementValue("Location", "London");

                data.Save(s.Stream); // got an error here: Specified method is not supported.
            }

            using (var myXML = new StreamWriter(dialog.OpenFile()))
            {
                var reader = new StreamReader(s.Stream);

                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = reader.ReadLine();
                    myXML.WriteLine(line.Trim());
                }
                myXML.Close();
            }
```

Need Help on this.

Thanks

Comment: I guess the reason is that you can't change the resources of your application like that.

Comment: mark the build action of that xml file as content, might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't place XML, that you are assuming to modify, as resource (resources are built into assembly file, so resource's modifying equals to modifying of *.dll file, that is not allowed).

Use file system or database or remote service in order to store this file.